# Make Python version depending on env var (using travis-ci)

Tags: python, django, continuous-integration, travis-ci

Is there a way to configure travis-ci to make the Python versions dependent on a certain env var?

Please consider the following `travis.yml` config:

```
language: python
python:
  - "2.5"
  - "2.6"
  - "2.7"
env:
  - DJANGO=1.3.4
  - DJANGO=1.4.2
  - DJANGO=https://github.com/django/django/zipball/master
install:
  - pip install -q Django==$DJANGO --use-mirrors
  - pip install -e . --use-mirrors
script:
  - python src/runtests.py
```

Among Django 1.3 (`DJANGO=1.3.4`) and 1.4 (`DJANGO=1.4.2`) i also want to test against the latest development version of Django (`DJANGO=https://github.com/django/django/zipball/master`), which is basically Django 1.5.

The problem i see is that travis-ci will automatically run the integration against **all** specified Python versions. Django 1.5 however doesn't support Python 2.5 anymore. Is it possible to omit it for the Django development version so that i get integrations like this only:

- DJANGO=1.3.4 --> python "2.5", "2.6", "2.7"
- DJANGO=1.4.2 --> python "2.5", "2.6", "2.7"
- DJANGO=https://github.com/django/django/zipball/master --> python "2.6", "2.7"

**UPDATE:**

Here's a link to a live example based on Odi's answer which i've been using successfully for a few months:
https://github.com/deschler/django-modeltranslation/blob/master/.travis.yml

Comment: Note: in the above example one would have to use `- DJANGO=Django==1.3.4` and `- pip install -q $DJANGO --use-mirrors` for direct installation from tarballs to work.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can specify configurations that you want to exclude from the build matrix (i.e. combinations that you don't want to test).

Add this to your `.travis.yml`:

```
matrix:
  exclude:
   - python: "2.5"
     env: DJANGO=https://github.com/django/django/zipball/master
```

**Note:** only *exact matches* will be excluded.

See the [build documentation (section *The Build Matrix*)](http://about.travis-ci.org/docs/user/build-configuration/#The-Build-Matrix) for further information.